# DB2 Query in MYSQL - foreign Key

Tags: mysql, db2, foreign-keys

I have this below ddl from a DB2 Database.

```
ALTER TABLE "DBName"."TableName" 
        ADD CONSTRAINT "FRNKEYAPPLICATIONID" FOREIGN KEY
                ("APPLICATION_ID")
        REFERENCES "DBName"."TableName"
                ("APPLICATION_ID")
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ENFORCED
        ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION;
```

We are migrating from DB2 to MYSQL.

What query should I use to replicate this is in MYSQL 5.7.11.

Am getting syntax error on "Enforced and Enable QUERY OPTIMIZATION line.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Enforced and Enable QUERY OPTIMIZATION are not options in 
 mysql  see - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 0):

As you can easily see in MySQL's documentation on [alter table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html), neither `enforced`, nor `enable query optimization` clauses are supported in MySQL.

The `enforced` attribute in DB2 simply indicates if the foreign key is enforced. In MySQL you cannot set this behaviour on foreign key level. You can only enable / disable **all** foreign key checks on session / global basis using the [foreign_key_checks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) server setting. You just have to make sure that this setting is turned on to replicate the enforced clause.

`enable query optimization` clause instructs DB2 to use the foreign key constraint to infer usage statistics, which in turn can be used to optimise query execution. There is nothing equivalent in MySQL, but this will not affect the overall behaviour of the foreign key.

Comment: `enable query optimization` clause allows DB2 to do query rewrite based on the constraint being true.